# SSMS18 - Default File Location (Changed ssms.Application.pkgdef)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have changed the DefaultProjectsLocation (SSMS18) from the default (My Documents) to a folder on my network. But when I run SSMS18 and open Projects it is still looking at the default location. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If using SSMS with a full install of SQL Server then there is a good answer on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/651535/management-studio-default-file-save-location).

If using SSMS as a standalone then the following should work

1. Locate C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Application
2. Open ssms.application.pkgdef with a text editor(e.g. Notepad)
3. Change the value of DefaultProjectsLocation
4. "DefaultProjectsLocation"="C:\MYNEWPATH"
5. Save the file

Comment: Thanks - my SSMS is standalone. I have changed the  DefaultProjectsLocation and reopened SSMS but my change has not been recognised and default is still as before. When I open ssms.application.pkgdef it still shows my change. So SSMS is not responding to my change.

Comment: Can you close all instances of SSMS and then try the change again ?

Comment: I have closed SSMS18 on all my PCs, opened ssms.application.pkgdef in Notepad and my change is still there. Saved the file again and opended SSMS18 and it is still pointing to the old path (which is not in the file anymore) rather than my new path.

Comment: I'm out of ideas